# Depreciation and capital gains on a rental condo in the US

Tags: united-states, irs, rental-property, depreciation

I rent out a condo that I purchased two years ago. I make a small profit. It may be advantageous for me to depreciate the condo. This presumably will increase the capital gains that will occur when it is sold. My question: Does the IRS insist that depreciation is taken or can I choose not to depreciate it?

Answer (score 3):

> Does the IRS insist that depreciation is taken or can I choose not to depreciate it?

**Yes**, the IRS will tax you on depreciation recapture whether or not you actual claim the depreciation. According to [this article](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/taking-depreciation-rental-property-hurt-sell-45457.html):

> not depreciating your property will not save you from the tax -- the IRS levies it on the depreciation that you should have claimed, whether or not you actually did.